# py2app and xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, py2app

I'm trying to build an app that uses some xml data using Python's built-in xml.etree.ElementTree class. It works properly when I run from the command line, but when I build it, I get an error "ImportError: No module etree.ElementTree." I'm guessing this is because I'm not importing that module correctly, but I haven't been able to figure out how. When I use the "includes" or "packages" directive, py2app complains with the same error, and when I specifically specify the package_dir (/System/Library/...), it compiles, but still gives me the error. I've included a short example to illustrate the issue.

macxml.py

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = ElementTree()
    print tree.parse('lib.xml')
```

This should print out "< Element Library at xxxxxx>" where Library is the root name.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="Mac XML Test",
      app=['macxml.py'],
     )
```

What is the correct way to make the mac app utilize this library?

Python 2.6.4

Mac OS X 10.6.2

Edit: I also tried this on another mac (PPC 10.5.8) with Python 2.6.2 and achieved the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling and updating macholib, modulegraph, py2app, and setuptools to no avail, I did a little more digging and found the following error in the modulegraph module:

```
graphmodule.find_modules.find_modules(includes=['xml.etree'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
    File ".../modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 255 in find_modules
    File ".../modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 182 in find_needed_modules
    File ".../modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 401 in import_hook
    File ".../modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 464 in load_tail
ImportError: No module named xml.etree
```

So I looked more into the `load_tail` and `import_hook` functions and found that for some reason it was importing the xml package correctly, but then went to an old install of _xmlplus to look for the etree subpackage (which of course it couldn't find). Removing the _xmlplus package eliminated the error and I was able to get the application to work with the following setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
import xml.etree.ElementTree

setup(name="Mac XML Test",
      app=['macxml.py'],
      options={'py2app': {'includes': ['xml.etree.ElementTree']}},
      data_files=[('', ['lib.xml'])]
     )
```

The output shows up in the console.

Comment: Assuming we did the same thing, this worked for me too. Since the following doesn't format well, I added it in a comment below. I edited find_modules.py and changed
    REPLACEPACKAGES = {
        '_xmlplus':     'xml',
    }
to 
    REPLACEPACKAGES = {
        #'_xmlplus':     'xml',
    }

Answer (score 1):

Since the comment doesn't have good formating,

In find_modules.py I changed

```
REPLACEPACKAGES = {
    '_xmlplus':     'xml',
}
```

To

```
REPLACEPACKAGES = {
    #'_xmlplus':     'xml',
}
```

And the xml import worked.

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest modulegraph @0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using macports (or fink etc.) make sure that `py2app` is using the correct interpreter. You may have to install a new version to work with 2.6.x (on OS X 10.5, `py2app` uses 2.4.x).

If that doesn't work my steps for working through path problems are:

1. Start up the python interpreter that your code (or `py2app`) uses (are you absolutely certain?? try `which python`)
2. `import sys; print sys.path`

If step 2. gives you a path in `/System/Library..someotherpythonversion` your code is running in the wrong interpreter.

Comment: I'm using the standard 2.6.4 install from python.org. The code seems to be running from the correct interpreter. Both `which python` and the sys.path point to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/`.

Comment: Must be some weird behaviour with `py2app` then, how did you install that? Have you tried running a script through `py2app` that prints the path?

Comment: You say "when I specifically specify the package_dir (/System/Library/...)".  If you are using the 2.6.4 python.org, there should not be any /System/Library/Framework/Python... paths.  Did you install a separate version of setuptools or Distribute for the python.org python and are you using that `easy_install` script (in the /Library/Frameworks.../bin directory) instead of the Apple-supplied easy_install in /usr/bin (which installs packages to the Apple-supplied python)?

Comment: I don't remember how I installed py2app, but python shows it's located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py2app-0.4.2-py2.6.egg`. Also, the version of python I'm using is the Mac OS X dmg file from python.org (since my mac only had 2.6.3), but I noticed when I open it it says "Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27, 2009, 19:48:23) [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin. setuptools shows I'm using v0.6c9-py2.6.egg. I will try reinstalling p2yapp, although I can't use easy_install from my current location b/c of the proxy.